In Top, *how* do conjugate homorphisms of groups induce homotopies of classifying maps?
In Top, how do conjugate homorphisms of groups induce homotopies of classifying spaces?
They exist— there's an abstract proof, but how is BG → BH written in terms of the homotopy??
If G and H are only H-spaces, a homomorphism induces a  map of a projective plane. In Top, how do conjugate H-maps  induce homotopies of  maps of  projective planes??

If I interpret your first question correctly, it's equivalent to asking for a group $G$ and $g \in G$ how to see the map $f_g\colon BG \rightarrow BG$ induced by the homomorphism $G \rightarrow G$ taking $x$ to $g x g^{-1}$.
Let $\ast \in BG$ be the base point, which I'll assume is non-degenerate (so the inclusion $\ast \hookrightarrow BG$ is a cofibration).  The map $f_g$ should take $\ast$ to $\ast$.  Let $\gamma\colon [0,1] \rightarrow BG$ be the loop based at $\ast$ corresponding to $g$. Using the homotopy extension property, we can find a homotopy $\phi_t\colon BG \rightarrow BG$ with $\phi_0 = \text{id}$ and $\phi_t(\ast) = \gamma(t)$.  The desired $f_g$ is then $f_g = \phi_1$.  This map is homotopic to the identity, but of course the base point moves during the homotopy.

There's a construction of $BG$ used quite often by geometric-oriented homotopy theorists that makes the homotopies quite explicit.   In this model for $BG$ you start by "resolving" $G$ to the homotopy-equivalent space of finite subsets of $[0,1]$ labelled by elements of $G$, with the rules that if two labelled points collide then their labels multiply.  To make this definition precise you have to take the disjoint union  $\bigsqcup_n \Delta_n \times G^n$ and mod out by the collision relation, given by maps of the boundary facets to $\Delta_{n-1} \times G^{n-1}$.   Here $\Delta_n = \{ (t_1,\dotsc, t_n) : 0 \leq t_1 \leq \dotsb \leq t_n \leq 1 \}$ is the $n$-simplex.   You similarly allow for the deletion of points labelled by the neutral element.
In this model there are two actions of $G$ on this "resolved" $G$, one by inserting a point on the left, and another by inserting a point on the right.  You mod out by one of these actions and you have a model for $EG$, and mod out by both to get $BG$.
Anyhow, so say you have a homomorphism $f : G \to H$, then the induced map of classifying spaces $Bf$ simply takes a collection of $G$-labelled points in $[0,1]$ and replaced them by the $H$-labelled points by applying $f$ to the labels.   So if all the labels are conjugated $x^{-1} f(g) x$ by a common element you can slide the leftmost $x^{-1}$ off the $0$ end of the interval, the rightmost $x$ off the $1$ end of the interval, and all the other $x^{-1}$ and $x$ pairs can slide together and cancel.   That would be the homotopy.
Dev Sinha gives the appropriate images to model this in his presentation: Geometry of Eilenberg-MacLane Spaces II - Iterated Bar.
It appears around the 18-minute mark.  But he goes into detail in the case of $\mathbb RP^\infty$.  Which might be what you are looking for.

Thanks, Ryan That does what I wanted to SEE as Dev shows. Now to see if it works for thier projective planes without associativity
